# DIT-MCO hardware with Rotary switch & Nixie Tubes?

Tags: rotary

I really needed some help. I can't for the life of me find any information pertaining to this hardware manufactured by the DIT-MCO Electronics Division. The most information I can glean is that It's a Type 45 switch and was made in Northlake Illinois and that it's attached to a rotary dial. Any information or applications for these pieces of hardware would be greatly appreciated! 
One more bonus, my grandfather also gave me a Nixie Tube display and I have yet to test it out. I'm not sure any specifications or what equipment to use with it to make sure I don't blow it up (figuratively); any information on the tubes would also be appreciated. Thanks!

[Here are pictures for the hardware!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGStj.jpg)

Comment: It looks similar to the British [Strowger switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strowger_switch) used in telephone exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a stepping switch. I refer you to the complete engineering information that an engineer  would have used in 1964- "[How to use Rotary Stepping Switches](http://www.telephonecollectors.info/index.php/document-repository/doc_view/10539-how-to-use-rotary-stepping-switches-automatic-electric-1964-ocr-r)" from Automatic Electric.

[image]

It's an 63MB 81-page book, scanned and linked above in it's entirety. If it disappears, look for the file named "10539-how-to-use-rotary-stepping-switches-automatic-electric-1964-ocr-r.pdf"

[image]